# How to make a script on an <a> tag work when the link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have this HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?register=reg"><img src="button2.png" id="button2"></a>
```

and i have this script:

```
$("#button2").on('click', function(e){ 
  $("#button2").css("display","none"); 
  $("#main").css("display","none"); 
  $("#register").css("display","block"); 
});
```

the link works but the script doesn't.

Comment: You should use `.hide()` and `.show()` rather than `.css()`.

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want the default action (i.e. going to `index.php?register=reg` to be deferred until the numerous CSS transformations have been applied?

Comment: I like to click to link hide the div box,button and show other div and include page with GET to the show div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the event from propagating from the "button" to the link:

```
$("#button2").on('click', function(e){ 
  e.stopPropagation(); // <======== This is the change
  $("#button2").css("display","none"); 
  $("#main").css("display","none"); 
  $("#register").css("display","block"); 
});
```

If you don't stop the event from propagating, it reaches the link, and the browser follows the link as usual.

Note that there are other ways to trigger that link than clicking the image on top of it; you might consider hooking the event on the link rather than on the "button" and using `e.preventDefault()` instead (to prevent the default behavior, which is to follow the link). Then again, it seems odd to have a genuine link you never want them to click...

BenM thinks you want the link to be followed, but only after the user has seen the changes you're making. You can do that, although it introduces an unnecessary delay in what the user is trying to do:

```
$("#button2").on('click', function(e){ 
  var link = this.href;
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#button2").css("display","none"); 
  $("#main").css("display","none"); 
  $("#register").css("display","block");
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = link;
  }, 500); // 500ms = half a second, adjust as desired
});
```

Comment: I think the OP needs the URL to be followed to. As far as I can tell, that should be deferred until the CSS transformations have been applied...

Comment: @BenM: It's possible, the question is really unclear. But "it doesn't just flash" is the usual sort of language people use when the page is refreshing and they don't realize it. If following the link were what they actually wanted, I'd expect the (new) page to be what they actually wanted.

Comment: If use the e.preventDefault() the script is work but the link is not

Comment: @user3140323: The whole point of `e.preventDefault` (assuming you're hooking the event on the *link*, not the "button" img) is to stop the link from being followed. As BenM says: Edit the question to be clear about what you're trying to achieve, but I think I've covered both of the things we can guess you're trying to do above, if you try what's actually there.

Comment: I like to click to link hide the div box,button and show other div and include page with GET to the show div

Answer (score 0):

If the link needs to be followed after the elements have been hidden/shown, you could try:

```
$("#button2").on('click', function(event){ 
  event.stopPropagation();
  var linkurl =  $(this).attr("href");
  $("#button2").hide(function() {
    $("#main").hide(function() {
      $("#register").show(function() {
        window.location.href = linkurl;
      });
    });
  }); 
});
```

Because we have used `event.stopPropagation();` we also make navigate to the new page using `window.location.href`.

Comment: hide and show doesnt work I like to click to link hide the div box,button and show other div and include page with GET to the show div